# How to format emacs buffer in markdown-mode on save

Tags: emacs, formatting, markdown, indentation

I have this in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'gofmt-before-save)
```

and it works for Go (on save the file is formatted properly).

I have installed and am using this [markdown-mode](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) and would like to setup similar behavior for `*.md` files, that is, format on save.  By *format* I mean make paragraphs no wider than some number of columns (e.g.,. 80), align all the list/sub-lists, etc. bullets, turn multiple consecutive white lines into a single one, and so on.

I don't really care about the actual formatting convention (if there are multiple out there, I have no idea), as long as it does the formatting on save.

I've searched but haven't been able to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[emacs-markdownfmt](https://github.com/nlamirault/emacs-markdownfmt) is an emacs package that wraps functionality provided by [markdownfmt](https://github.com/shurcooL/markdownfmt). It seems like you'd want the `markdownfmt-format-buffer` function.

That said, given that it wasn't in the context of the question, you're probably want to have those hooks based on more specific modes (golang, markdown, etc). Probably not a good idea to hang a bunch of stuff on `before-save-hook` for every mode you ever configure. Might make your emacs significantly slow